# Cloudformation Macro to use Cross Region Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created a cloudformation macro(region - us-east-1) which depends on a Lambda which resides in different account and different region(us-east-2). During execution of CFN, the Macro is failing. But if I create the same Lambda in same region i.e. us-east-1, the CFN is working fine.

Does Macro not support cross region lambda?
Can someone provide a way to have a lambda in different region from the macro.

Comment: Other CloudFormation features like custom resources require the same region, so this might be the case here too. Consider using a stack set to easily deploy the same resource to multiple regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros should always be backed by a Lambda function and Lambda Function and this Macro should reside in a same region.

You can have cross account invocation model as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html#template-macros-permissions) but still need to make sure that Macro and Lambda are in same region even across different accounts.